# Script to produces Kubernetes manifests to deploy bare nginx container

Tags: nginx, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress, nginx-config, nginx-location

I would like to have a script that produces Kubernetes manifests to deploy a bare nginx container with service port 80 and ingress for host as example.nginx.com. I will deploy it into EKS cluster. Can someone give me clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I started configuring NLB with Nginx controller on EKS. So documenting the complete flow with the script you needed.
I tried other approached like cloud provider based Nginx deployment but it didn't work as expected ( instead of ELB it was creating Classic LB).
Ref- https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6292

In short below approach is the best so far.

1. Install Nginx controller- This will create a deployment and a NodePort service for HTTP say port- 31848, HTTPS- 30099

`#kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.0.1/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml`

2. Create Production deployment, service and ingress resource.

> ```
> apiVersion: apps/v1
> kind: Deployment
> metadata:
>   name: production
>   labels:
>     app: production
>   namespace: app 
> spec:
>   replicas: 1
>   selector:
>     matchLabels:
>       app: production
>   template:
>     metadata:
>       labels:
>         app: production
>     spec:
>       containers:
>       - name: production
>         image: mirrorgooglecontainers/echoserver:1.10
>         ports:
>         - containerPort: 8080
>         env:
>           - name: NODE_NAME
>             valueFrom:
>               fieldRef:
>                 fieldPath: spec.nodeName
>           - name: POD_NAME
>             valueFrom:
>               fieldRef:
>                 fieldPath: metadata.name
>           - name: POD_NAMESPACE
>             valueFrom:
>               fieldRef:
>                 fieldPath: metadata.namespace
>           - name: POD_IP
>             valueFrom:
>               fieldRef:
>                 fieldPath: status.podIP
>
> ---
>
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Service
> metadata:
>   name: production
>   labels:
>     app: production
>   namespace: app
> spec:
>   ports:
>   - port: 80
>     targetPort: 8080
>     protocol: TCP
>     name: http
>   selector:
>     app: production
> ---
>
> apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
> kind: Ingress
> metadata:
>   name: production
>   annotations:
>     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
>   namespace: app
> spec:
>   rules:
>   - http:
>       paths:
>         - path: /
>           pathType: Prefix
>           backend:
>             serviceName: production
>             servicePort: 80
> ```

3. Create Canary Deployment.

> ```
> apiVersion: apps/v1
> kind: Deployment
> metadata:
>   name: canary
>   labels:
>     app: canary
>   namespace: app 
> spec:
>   replicas: 1
>   selector:
>     matchLabels:
>       app: canary
>   template:
>     metadata:
>       labels:
>         app: canary
>     spec:
>       containers:
>       - name: canary
>         image: mirrorgooglecontainers/echoserver:1.10
>         ports:
>         - containerPort: 8080
>         env:
>           - name: NODE_NAME
>             valueFrom:
>               fieldRef:
>                 fieldPath: spec.nodeName
>           - name: POD_NAME
>             valueFrom:
>               fieldRef:
>                 fieldPath: metadata.name
>           - name: POD_NAMESPACE
>             valueFrom:
>               fieldRef:
>                 fieldPath: metadata.namespace
>           - name: POD_IP
>             valueFrom:
>               fieldRef:
>                 fieldPath: status.podIP
> ---
>
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Service
> metadata:
>   name: canary
>   labels:
>     app: canary
>   namespace: app
> spec:
>   ports:
>   - port: 80
>     targetPort: 8080
>     protocol: TCP
>     name: http
>   selector:
>     app: canary
> ---
>
> apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
> kind: Ingress
> metadata:
>   name: canary
>   annotations:
>     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
>     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: "true"
>     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-weight: "30"
>   namespace: app
> spec:
>   rules:
>   - http:
>       paths:
>         - path: /
>           pathType: Prefix
>           backend:
>             serviceName: canary
>             servicePort: 80
> ```

4. Create a NLB type Load Balancer on EKS. If you are choosing "internet-facing".
5. Create a Target Group with "Target Type" as instance and Port/Health Check Port- 31848 (HTTP).
6. Attach Target Group to Autoscaling group.
7. Create a listener on NLB (TLS- Secure TCP) and forward it to the Target Group.
8. Although we would be launching worker nodes on Private subnets but we need to open port "31848" for all the IP. This is how EC2 would be able to communicate with NLB.

Hope I am able to provide you clear idea on this. Please do let me know in case you face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must have [deployed nginx-ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws) to your cluster. Then run the following script at your command prompt to deploy `a bare nginx container with service port 80 and ingress for host as example.nginx.com`:

```
cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:alpine
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.nginx.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx
            port:
              number: 80
EOF
```